# Help with Compiler Error C2440 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

i am getting a C2440 compiler error when i build my program but cant figure out how to fix it

Here is the line it comes up on:

```
if((*Iter)->classID != classID && (*Iter)->getX() == (int)pos.x && (int)(*Iter)->getY == (int)pos.y)
```

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: What is Iter? Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing `()` in your `getY` call:

`(int)(*Iter)->getY` should probably be `(int)(*Iter)->getY()`

Comment: I agree this looks like an error too (+1), but I don't think it's the error the compiler's complaining about here. At least, I don't think that can cause an invalid type conversion message.

Comment: @Billy: It *sort of* made sense to me (type conversion of function pointer to int rather than the return value), but it was the first thing that immediately stood out :)

Comment: @Billy: Could the invalid type conversion be the attempt to cast a function pointer (i.e. getY) to an integer?  (Haven't compiled it myself.)

Comment: @Demian: Member function pointers can only be accessed using the address-of (`&`) operator -- unlike free functions the specification of the function pointer is not an implicit part of the name.

Comment: @Eric: No -- that would have to be a member function pointer which cannot be accessed that way -- if that is the intent than it shouldn't parse, much less convert types correctly.

Comment: @Billy: I have been schooled. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess its this part`(*Iter)->getX() == (int)pos.x` and perhaps it needs to be `(int)(*Iter)->getX() == (int)pos.x`. This is just a shot in the dark based on the `(int)(*Iter)->getY == (int)pos.y`part of the expression. More code/context would be really helpful though. And as Demian Brecht pointed out, perhaps the `()` is missing on this part of the expression as well.